# iOS: Problem to send big files (more than 3Gb) with OutputStream(url: , append:) => Code Status 500

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, outputstream, urlsession

I try to send big video files with the OutputStream(url: payloadFileURL, append:) function but I have a **code status 500**. (I precise that when I send 1gb, 2gb it works like a charm)

Here is the entire code: [Send big files with OutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53784578/3581620)

```
private func buildPayloadFile(videoFileURL: URL, boundary: String, fileName: String, eventId: Int, contactId: Int, type: Int) throws -> URL {
    let mimetype = "video/mp4"

    let payloadFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
        .appendingPathComponent(UUID().uuidString)

    guard let stream = OutputStream(url: payloadFileURL, append: false) else {
        throw UploadError.unableToOpenPayload(payloadFileURL)
    }

    stream.open()

    //define the data post parameter
    stream.write("--\(boundary)\r\n")
    stream.write("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"eventId\"\r\n\r\n")
    stream.write("\(eventId)\r\n")

    stream.write("--\(boundary)\r\n")
    stream.write("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"contactId\"\r\n\r\n")
    stream.write("\(contactId)\r\n")

    stream.write("--\(boundary)\r\n")
    stream.write("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"type\"\r\n\r\n")
    stream.write("\(type)\r\n")

    stream.write("--\(boundary)\r\n")
    stream.write("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"\(fileName)\"\r\n")
    stream.write("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
    if stream.append(contentsOf: videoFileURL) < 0 {
        throw UploadError.unableToOpenVideo(videoFileURL)
    }
    stream.write("\r\n")

    stream.write("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
    stream.close()

    return payloadFileURL
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: a 500 error is an error on the server side, you could be exceeding the max post size or something

Comment: @Scriptable I tried with Postman directly without passing with iOS, it works like a charm with 5Gb file. There is something missing in iOS I think?

Comment: if thats the case, then yes, something in your iOS code is not correct and causing an error on the server.

Comment: @Scriptable But why with 3Gb and not 2Gb? It is strange ?

Comment: not sure tbh, that is strange. I would just try to mimic your Postman request as much as possible. compare the code... postman can actually generate the code for this in Swift

Comment: Oh ok, I am going to check that code with Postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 500 means a server side problems. There can be several reasons:
- server side configuration
- server disk space
- problem with server implementation

Please also check your client code:
- Content Type
- Mime type
- Enough space on device. Because of this big file, it will need more space on the device to store in memory during "cache"

Comment: Exact, that was the device space problem! The code status 500 internal server error is very misleading...

Comment: If it is that kind of problem, your client code might have sent truncated packets to the server